# Embed image data (png or pdf) inside tex document

Tags: graphics, pdf, include, inline, png

Is there a way to include (or "inline") raw image data or pdf data inside the tex document itself, such that it becomes stand-alone? Something like this:

```
\inlinedata[base64]{theimage}{AJDeafg82asd34z8BNFKW(...more base64...)SKJWKUFr=}
...
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{theimage}
```

That would sure come very handy for some super-portable documents, where two or three small external images would too easily get lost. (Please try to keep the lectures why external resources are *always* so much better as brief as possible ;)

Comment: Yes, thank you! The solution (at least for png and jpg) is:
https://github.com/zerotoc/pdfinlimg

Comment: Good find! Would you mind posting that as a self-answer to your question?

Answer (score 4):

The solution for png and jpg is:
https://github.com/zerotoc/pdfinlimg.
haven't found one for pdf (yet).

(Thanks for pointing me into the correct direction, Jake!)